# two way data binding is not working with expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular world. I have just written my first program in angularJS. But its not working in the way I am expecting. Here is the code.

```js
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
sampleApp.controller('FinanceController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.salary = 0;
    $scope.invest = 0;
    $scope.result = function() {
      return $scope.salary * $scope.invest * 0.01;
    }
    $scope.result2 = $scope.salary * $scope.invest * 0.01;
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sampleApp">

<head>

</head>

<body ng-controller="FinanceController">
  Salary
  <input type="text" name="salary" ng-model="salary">
  <br>Percentage to spend on gadgets
  <input type="text" name="invest" ng-model="invest">
  <br>
  <span>Case1: Total Amount in Rs. {{result()}} </span>
  <br/>
  <span>Case2: Total Amount in Rs. {{result2}} </span>

</body>

</html>
```

I do not understand why my case2 does not show correct result?

Comment: `result2` isnt on the scope.

Comment: result2 just "runs" once and "returns" a plain old number, which never updates.

Comment: @dandavis But as per angular two way data binding it should have updated each time any of the two variable changes Isn't it?

Comment: no, if it did, that same code would be setting salary and invest to 0 each change, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see the value, [and not manipulate it], change your html to

```
<span>Case2: Total Amount in Rs. {{salary * invest * 0.01}} </span>
```

As per the comments, the assignment is done only once. The right side of the assignment statement returns a value, and that is assigned to the scope variable and the business ends there.

> To add up, Angular Data binding automatically updates the immediate variable that is bound to an input element in the view, not the variables that is formed by some expression that is constructed using this immediate variable.

If you actually want to store and manipulate that value, You should go by using $watch as suggested by another answer..

Answer (score 1):

`result2` calculate only once and never update. you may need `$watch` to update it whenever `salary` and `invest` changed.

like:

```
$scope.$watch('salary+invest', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.result2 = $scope.salary * $scope.invest * 0.01;
});
```